# Angular2 filter an array of objects based on an array of strings

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives

I have an array of Users in where every user has a name (`user.name`):

`let users = Array<User>();`

Imagine I have this array of strings I want to filter `users` array based on the next array of strings:

```
let filterargs = ['Lau', 'Za'];
```

This is my markup:

```
<li *ngFor="let user of usersList | filter: filterargs; let i = index;">
```

This is my pipe filter but it isn't working:

```
import {Pipe, Injectable, PipeTransform} from "@angular/core";

@Pipe({name: 'filter', pure: false})
@Injectable()
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

    transform(items: any[], args: any[]): any {
        // filter items array, items which match and return true will be kept, false will be filtered out
        return items.filter(item => item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(args[0].name.toLowerCase()) !== -1);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use `args[0].toLowerCase()` instead of `args[0].name.toLowerCase()`

Answer (score 6):

I think your filter function is not correct.
try doing :

```
return items.filter(item => item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(args[0].toLowerCase()) !== -1);
```

Hope this Helps.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you:

```
return items.filter(item => item[0].name.toLowerCase().indexOf(args[0].toLowerCase()) !== -1);
```

I had a similar issue with objects in an array, by adding the [0], it worked for me.